# Configure FreeIPA from the script using a silent install

Tags: centos, silent-installer, freeipa

I have a question about a silent install, would it be the same as an unintended install? For FreeIPA I checked the man ipa-server-install and it only showed -U --unintended and not silent. How would I make it configure in a silent install?

[SCRIPT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tiggq.png)